# web client host identification (like Netflix)

Tags: javascript, web, clientid

I'm developing a website, in which I need to ensure that some pages won't be opened in more than one tab / browser. I need some sort of client identification. As I know MAC address cannot be queried using javascript.

I know that Netflix does something just like this, when opening two tabs of video watching, Netflix prompt an error that I'm already watching. Even if I'm using a different browser, Netflix can still tell I have another browser which is watching a video, which means they don't use cookies for this.

So in short, how can a web app distinguish between computers? How Netflix does that?

Comment: how about generating some random string in the __sessionStorage__, and on server side check the couple ip/randomStringGiven (two tabs==two different strings, two browsers == two different strings)?

Comment: But on the server I can only get the **external** IP. Two users with the same external IP can still work concurrently (in the case of Netflix)